# Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php

よくわかるPHPの教科書で学習中で掲示板を作成中なのですが、以下のエラーが解除できません。

```
Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\post\index.php on line 35
```

参考にした記事
[Undefined index: page in - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468275/undefined-index-page-in)
[「Notice: Undefined index」と表示されるとき](https://php1st.com/574) 
[Notice: Undefined indexエラーの原因と解決方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/wakahara3/items/bb7c8d7a1673b161abe7)

```
<?php
session_start();
require('../dbconnect.a.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && $_SESSION['time'] + 3600 > time()) {
    //ログインしている
    $_SESSION['time'] = time();

    $members = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM members WHERE id=?');
    $members->execute(array($_SESSION['id']));
    $member = $members->fetch();
} else {
    // ログインしてない
    header('Location: login.php'); 
    exit();
}

// 投稿を記録する
if(!empty($_POST['message'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['message'] != '')); {
    $message = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO posts SET member_id=?, message=?, reply_post_id=?, created=NOW()');
    $message->execute(array(
      $member['id'],
      $_POST['message'],
      $_POST['reply_post_id']
  ));

  header('Location: index.php');
  exit();

    }
}

//投稿を取得する
$page = $_REQUEST['page'];
if ($page == '') {
    $page = 1;
}
$page = max($page, 1);

//最終ページを取得する
$counts = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM posts');
$cnt = $counts->fetch();
$maxPage = ceil($cnt['cnt'] / 5);
$page = min($page, $maxPage);

$start = ($page - 1) * 5;

$posts = $db->prepare('SELECT m.name, m.picture, p.* FROM members m, posts p WHERE m.id=p.member_id ORDER BY p.created DESC LIMIT ?, 5');
$posts->bindParam(1, $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$posts->execute();

//返信の場合
if (isset($_REQUEST['res'])) {
    $response = $db->prepare('SELECT m.name, m.picture, p.* FROM members m,posts p WHERE m.id=p.member_id AND p.id=? ORDER BY p.created DESC');
    $response->execute(array($_REQUEST['res']));

    $table = $response->fetch();
    $message = '＠' . $table['name'] . ' ' . $table['message'];
}

//htmlspecialcharsのショートカット
function h($value) {
    return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES);
}

//本文内のURLにリンクを設定します
function makeLink($value) {
    return mb_ereg_replace("(https?)(://[[:alnum:]\+\$;\?\.%,!#~*/:@&=_-]+)", '<a href="\1\2">\1\2</a>' , $value);
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

        <title> Haratter ：投稿画面</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
      <h1 class="font-weight-nomal">ひとこと掲示板</h1>
    </header>
<main>
<pre>
<div id="content">
<form action="" method="post">
<dl>
<dt><font size="3"><?php echo h($member['name']); ?>さん、メッセージをどうぞ</font></dt>
<dd>
<textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="5"><?php 
if (isset($message)) {
echo h($message);
}
?></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="reply_post_id" value="<?php echo h($_REQUEST['res']); ?>" />
</dd>
</dl>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="投稿する" />
</div>
</form>
</div>

<?php
foreach ($posts as $post):
?>
<div class="msg">
<img src="member_picture/<?php echo h($post['picture']); ?>" width="48" height="48" alt="<?php echo h($post['name']); ?>" />
<p><?php echo makeLink(h($post['message'])); ?><span class="name">(<?php echo h($post['name']); ?>)</span>
[<a href="index.php?res=<?php echo h($post['id']); ?>">Re</a>]</p>
<p class="day"><a href="view.php?id=<?php echo h($post['id']); ?>"><?php echo h($post['created']); ?></a>
<?php
if ($post['reply_post_id'] > 0):
?>
<a href="view.php?id=<?php echo h($post['reply_post_id']); ?>">返信元のメッセージ</a>
<?php
endif;
?>
<?php
if ($_SESSION['id'] == $post['member_id']):
?>
   [<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo h($post['id']); ?>" style="color:#F33;">削除</a>]
<?php
endif;
?>
</p>
</div>
<?php
endforeach;
?>

<ul class="paging">
<?php
if ($page > 1) {
?>
<li><a href="index.php?page=<?php print($page - 1); ?>">前のページへ</a></li>
<?php
} else {
?>
<li>前のページへ</li>
<?php
}
?>
<?php
if ($page < $maxPage) {
?>
<li><a href="index.php?page=<?php print($page + 1); ?>">次のページへ</a></li>
<?php
} else {
?>
<li>次のページへ</li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
</pre>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 他のパラメータと同様に存在するかどうかのチェックが必要では？ [PHP リクエストパラメータ $_REQUEST\['リクエストパラメータ名'\]](https://qiita.com/icelandnono/items/2cb7c281ac52dd7bdbd0)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。issetやemptyを使って存在するかどうかのチェックを試みたのですが、なかなかエラーが解除できずで悩んでおりました。参考記事載せていただきありがとうございます。拝見いたします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

外部から渡された値をほかの部分では[isset](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.isset.php)や[empty](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.empty.php)を使って存在チェックしているので同様の存在チェックが必要です。

ここでいう外部から渡された値とは
$_GET
$_POST
$_COOKIE
$_REQUEST
以上の変数を使う場合は必ず存在チェックをしましょう。

いくらページの仕様上パラメータが渡っていないことがないとしても、
Webの仕組み上リクエストはいくらでも不正に送信できるのでかならずわたってくる値のチェックは行いましょう。

今回の場合はpageの値が渡ってこないときの処理をどうするか決める必要があります。（エラーとするのか？初期値をいれるのか？）
仮に初期値１を入れるとすると[null合体演算子](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)を利用するとシンプルで使いやすいと思います。

```
//投稿を取得する
$page = $_REQUEST['page'] ?? 1;
if ($page == '') {
    $page = 1;
}
$page = max($page, 1);
```

アプリケーションの仕様を決めてもらってどういう運用がいいか決めていきましょう。

### 追記

大事なことはissetで書くことやemptyで書くことではないです。
「したいこと」を書くことです。
emptyもissetも似た様な書き方はできます。

issetの場合

```
$page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1;
if ($page == '') {
    $page = 1;
}
$page = max($page, 1);
```

emptyの場合

```
$page = empty($_REQUEST['page']) ? 1 : $_REQUEST['page'];
if ($page == '') {
    $page = 1;
}
$page = max($page, 1);
```

ですが厳密いうとこれらは違います。
たとえば数値の0が入ってきた場合や空の配列が入ってきた場合などです。

```
//emptyでもtrue;issetでもtrueになってしまい挙動が変わる
$_REQUEST['page'] = 0; 
$_REQUEST['page'] = [];
```

なのでどういうアプリケーションの仕様がいいか決めてもらってからコードを書く必要があります。

Comment: ご丁寧なご説明有難うございます。上記で解決いたしました！！ null合体演算子を使えばよかったのですね。`$page = $_REQUEST['page']  = null;`とかでは試してみたのですが、そうするとエラーは消えましたが次のページが表示されなくなってしまい完全に八方ふさがりになってしまいました。また、emptyやissetでも存在のチェックを試みたのですが、エラーが解除できなかったのでempty,issetで存在のチェックをするとしたらどういうコードになるのか、お手数をおかけしますがご教授いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 追記しました。大事なことは実現したいことを書きましょう。

Comment: こちらを参考にしてください。「[回答がついたら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)」ありがとうというコメントは不要です